# Right way to make changes in Wordpress Core

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently have removed the excerpt function from Wordpress and made my own so I can allow some HTML to be shown in the excerpt. I made the changes in a child theme functions file.

It was working fine on the front-end but after that I had problems on the back-end of Wordpress. In `/wp-admin/edit.php` in an excerpt of posts I get the post excerpt with all the HTML tags so it was really hard to read the actual content of post.

To fix that I did a change in the Wordpress core file `/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php`.
I removed content from line 1037.

```
echo esc_html( get_the_excerpt() );
```

the function `esc_html`

How can I make this change permanent so that after a possible update of Wordpress, the change will not be lost?

Is this change safe? I will have a lot of users in my back-end of Wordpress.

## UPDATE MY QUESTION

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'my_clean_excerpt' );
function wpse_allowedtags() {
    // Add custom tags to this string
        return '<style>,<br>,<em>,<i>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>,<a>,<p>,<img>,<video>,<audio>,<div>,<wbr>'; 
    }

if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt' ) ) : 

    function wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($wpse_excerpt) {
    $raw_excerpt = $wpse_excerpt;
        if ( '' == $wpse_excerpt ) {

            $wpse_excerpt = get_the_content('');
            $wpse_excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $wpse_excerpt );
            $wpse_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $wpse_excerpt);
            $wpse_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $wpse_excerpt);
            //$wpse_excerpt = strip_tags($wpse_excerpt, wpse_allowedtags()); /*IF you need to allow just certain tags. Delete if all tags are allowed */

            //Set the excerpt word count and only break after sentence is complete.
                $excerpt_word_count = 75;
                $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 
                $tokens = array();
                $excerptOutput = '';
                $count = 0;

                // Divide the string into tokens; HTML tags, or words, followed by any whitespace
                preg_match_all('/(<[^>]+>|[^<>\s]+)\s*/u', $wpse_excerpt, $tokens);

                foreach ($tokens[0] as $token) { 

                    if ($count >= $excerpt_length && preg_match('/[\,\;\?\.\!]\s*$/uS', $token)) { 
                    // Limit reached, continue until , ; ? . or ! occur at the end
                        $excerptOutput .= trim($token);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Add words to complete sentence
                    $count++;

                    // Append what's left of the token
                    $excerptOutput .= $token;
                }

            $wpse_excerpt = trim(force_balance_tags($excerptOutput));

                $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;' . sprintf(__( 'Read more about: %s &nbsp;&raquo;', 'wpse' ), get_the_title()) . '</a>'; 
                $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end); 

                //$pos = strrpos($wpse_excerpt, '</');
                //if ($pos !== false)
                // Inside last HTML tag
                //$wpse_excerpt = substr_replace($wpse_excerpt, $excerpt_end, $pos, 0); /* Add read more next to last word */
                //else
                // After the content
                //$wpse_excerpt .= $excerpt_more; /*Add read more in new paragraph */
            
            // Extra filter to remove the above text from excerpt
            $badwords = array( 
            '< !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">',
            '< ?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>',
            );
            foreach ( $badwords as $badword ) {
            $wpse_excerpt = str_replace( $badword, '', $wpse_excerpt);
            }
            //End extra filrer
            return $wpse_excerpt;   

        }
        return apply_filters('wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $wpse_excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
    }

endif; 

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

I used this function to add html tags in excerpt.

I after updated the excerpts in database. And i get the result that i wanted.

But i get this in backend.
[problem backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1dgn.png)

So a fast way to get away with the problem was to go to `/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php`  and remove the function `esc_html` from this line `echo esc_html( get_the_excerpt() );` where the excerpt is generated for back-end.

So my question is not about how to allow html tags in excerpt, I already did that, but how to make that change permanent.

My back-end after that change. [Back-end after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq9oC.png)
That is what i want to do.

Comment: by making a plugin

Comment: You may get better help for your exact requirements here: (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt) and also check this as well (https://wpwhatnot.com/allow-html-excerpts/)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: I updated my question , maybe is more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Don't ever change WP core... You'll lose the ability to update it and your system will be vulnerable.

You can create plugins to change the excerpt behavior, you can create your own functions and use it in your theme templates...

There is a lot of ways better than to t

Comment: You are right, How can I make a plugin that did that change of my example in the file, i am beginner.

Comment: For a start, you should go to Wordpress Codex and read about plugins, hooks and the overall functions you wanna change. After that, it's basically a common PHP development project.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions , in your answer you said that i will lost the ability to update. You mean that, the Wordpress will not auto update because i have changed the core;  Or you saying that i would not do the update , so i don't lose the changes that i made;

Comment: The second option, if you update your WP, all your changes will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Never change the core of the WordPress. As Artur Luiz Oliveira mentioned you will lose those changes the first time WordPress will update, and you should be aware that it will do that automatically once the version becomes very dated if you like it or not.

To do what you are looking for I would suggest you look into [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/141125).

Might be more coding involved but this will stick and won't be affected when the WordPress version updates.